# Layered navigation not working with search results?

Tags: magento2, search, magento2.4.3

a little help if possible, please.
I cannot get layered navigation working with search results i.e. no filters?
Works perfectly when browsing the website with all filters showing the correct results etc...
I checked through the settings including the obvious "Use in search results layered navigation" which is set to "Yes" for all appropriate attributes.
Any ideas???
Magento 2.4.3 | Amasty Improved layered Navigation and several others from Amasty.

Comment: Could anyone suggest how to fault find a problem like this? I assume something is blocking the filters being diplayed and would like some advice on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months ago I had the same issue. Make sure that default search is set to Elastic search (I used Sphinx which caused the issue).
If you are on a development server you might also consider disabling Amasty Improved layered Navigation and see if layered navigation works with search results.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have tried disabling the Amasty module but sadly it made no difference. Regarding the Elastic search setting, that is interesting? I currently use Amasty Elastic search but could try switching it back to normal?

Comment: No dice with the Elastic Search settings either :(

Answer (score 0):

Set Enable Ajax to No in Amasty - Improved Layered Navigation extension.
https://nimb.ws/QB4RpO

If you are using Porto Theme then disable Mageplaza Ajax & Mageplaza Layered Navigation extension.